# Boost property tree xml parsing No such node ()

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm trying to parse an XML file using the boost/propert_tree library. I can get the xml file correctly and everything, but when I look for childs, it doesn't find any.

I have an input.xml file:

```
<ax:hello someatribute:ax="dwadawfesfjsefs">
    <something>523523</something>
    <ax:whatever>
        <ax:service_tree>
            <ax:service>some</ax:service>
            <ax:url>someulr</ax:url>
        </ax:service_tree>
    </ax:whatever>
</ax:hello>
```

The function where I try to parse the xml:

```
void parseXml(std::istream &stream)
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree pt;
    read_xml(stream, pt);
    BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type const &value, pt.get_child("ax:hello"))
    {
        std::cout << value.first;
    }
}
```

And the main function:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream stream("input.xml");
    parseXml(stream);
    return 0;
}
```

The error message I get is:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
>     what():  No such node (ax:hello)
>   Aborted (core dumped)`

As you can see, the `ax:hello` tag is properly opened and closed, so it should be able to find it despite the attributes, right?

Hope someone knows what's going on in here!

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something else wrong/different:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08e67a65c43b4847)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

void parseXml(std::istream &stream)
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree pt;
    read_xml(stream, pt);
    BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type const &value, pt.get_child("ax:hello"))
    {
        std::cout << value.first << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream stream(R"(
        <ax:hello someatribute:ax="dwadawfesfjsefs">
            <something>523523</something>
            <ax:whatever>
                <ax:service_tree>
                    <ax:service>some</ax:service>
                    <ax:url>someulr</ax:url>
                </ax:service_tree>
            </ax:whatever>
        </ax:hello>
)");
    parseXml(stream);
}
```

Prints

```
<xmlattr>
something
ax:whatever
```

Somewhat more elaborate dumping:

```
void dump(ptree const& pt, std::string const& indent = "") {
    for (auto& node : pt) {
        std::cout << indent << node.first;
        auto value = boost::trim_copy(node.second.get_value(""));
        if (!value.empty())
            std::cout << ": '" << value << "'";
        std::cout << "\n";
        dump(node.second, indent + "    ");
    }
}
```

Prints **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5911ea4031a631a5) too</kbd>**

```
ax:hello
    <xmlattr>
        someatribute:ax: 'dwadawfesfjsefs'
    something: '523523'
    ax:whatever
        ax:service_tree
            ax:service: 'some'
            ax:url: 'someulr'
```

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work when passing an istream with a file instead of a istringstream? Could you explain what `auto` does in the `dump` function? Which type would it be?

Comment: There's no difference. Obviously i used you code + file locally. The dump function is just for demo and uses c++11

Comment: Yes there is, or at least I'm doing it wrong, that's why I posted the question. It doesn't find any nodes when I do it from a file.

Comment: Yes it does. I showed you exactly that. If you don't want to hear it,  fine. Look for the other differences. Wrong file, wrong path, wrong encoding, you know. Debug it.

Comment: I did, that's why I asked the question here. Your code saves the contents of input.xml directly inside a istringstream, instead of loading the file into a ifstream. Still thanks for the answer because I was able to keep going.

Comment: I don't know what to say. [There is no difference](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c0fd4e8c177661f). Like I told you several times. I don't care what you choose to believe. Good luck. ([bonus](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/262954ad1d3e828e))

Comment: Like I told you, there is a big difference between copy-pasting a file into the code and loading a file to the program at runtime. Your code is correct? Yes. Does it work as I want? No. Why? because instead of loading the file with ifstream it's a simple copy-paste of the contents into a variable.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion you must be blind.